# InTune Device Management using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

Does anyone know what happens to an enrolled InTune device if the device is deleted via the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/device_delete)? Does that wipe the managed data on the device and remove it from InTune?

I cannot seem to find any documentation that answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "Delete" The managed device (enrolled device), it will remove the device from list All Devices.

And the most important, you can't manage the device again, for example if you use Windows Autopilot your device will be stuck - cannot login.

*both Graph API or Direct from Azure AD give same result*

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in your link are used to delete a Azure AD registered device, not used to delete the managed devices in Intune. So the answer for your question is "No", if you want to delete managed devices and wipe data in Intune using Microsoft Graph API, you should run the DELETE & POST requests as the followings:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/{id}/wipe
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/{id}
```

For more details about the Intune Graph API, please refer to docs [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/intune_graph_overview).

Comment: What is the id we are passing. It is id we get in user https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/